# Adjusting height of two divs based on it's parent's height

Tags: javascript, html, css

jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/7087s2dm/2/

I have two divs, #one and #two, inside div #parent.

Here, #one has it's height equal to 50% width of the screen. However, #two has it's height based on it's content.

I need to make the div#two's height increases to match that of div#one, even as width of page changes, If the width of page becomes small enough that div#one's height becomes smaller than div#two height, then the height of div#two should be limited to the content itself.

html:

```
<div id = "parent">
<div id="one">
    <img src ="https://gp6.googleusercontent.com/-P53UB3pztC8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/edcApVyNYJc/s48-c-k-no/photo.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="two">
    <span>Hello</span><br />
    <span>Hello</span><br />
    <span>Hello</span><br />
    <span>Hello</span><br />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #parent{
    background-color:yellow;
    max-width:500px;
    height:300px;
}
#one{
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
    width:50%;
}
#one img{
    width:50%;
    margin:25%;
}
#two{
    padding:2%;
    float:right;
    background-color:red;
    width:50%;
    margin-bottom:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
#two span{
    margin:10px;
}
```

What is the best way to do this? Can it be done with simple css? Or do i need to use JS?

Comment: i can't see any `height` set to `#one`.

Comment: Since the width of `#one img` is set to 50%, the `height` of `#one` will change proportionally. In fact, it is exactly equal to 50% of width assuming the image is a square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make it in simple css use `display:table`

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7087s2dm/3/)**

**CSS**

```
#parent{
    background-color:yellow;
    width:500px;
    display:table;
}
#one{
    background-color:red;
    width:50%;
    display: table-cell;
}

#one img{
    width:50%;
}
#two{
    background-color:red;
    width:50%;    display: table-cell;
    margin-bottom:0;
    vertical-align:top;
}
#two span{
    margin:10px;
}
```